# C++, ostream error when passing argument in CBuilder 2010

Tags: c++, error-handling, ostream, c++builder-2010, codeguard

What is wrong in this source code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>

void printTest ( std::ostream * o )
{
    *o << "test" << std::endl;
}


int main ( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
  std::ostream * o = &std::cout;
  char ot[4096];
  strcpy ( ot, "test.txt" );
  strcat ( ot, ".log" );
  static std::ofstream of ( ot );
  printTest ( o );  //Print to console OK
  o = & of;
  printTest ( o );  //Print to file: CodeGuard stops the application with the error log
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile this source code under CBuilder 2010 (enabled CodeGuard). The application has been stopped by CodeGuard with the following error log:

```
25.12.2011 13:00:57 started a CodeGuard(tm) process: Project3.exe(2244)  
Bad parameter in process: Project3.exe(2244)  - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/fstream#55
A bad file or pipe stream (0x32AF36D4) has been passed to the function.
0x0040A150 Call to fputc(0x74 ['t'], 0x32AF36D4)
0x004098A5 - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/fstream#55
0x004081BE - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/fstream#246
0x00407E2B - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/streambuf#465
0x004020AD - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/streambuf#151
0x00401434 - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/ostream#683
0x00401276 - File3.cpp#13
Pointer arithmetic underrun in process: Project3.exe(2244)  - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/streambuf#207
0x00892501-512, that is at offset 1-512 in heap block 0x00892500 (size 512).
0x0040985E - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/streambuf#207
0x00408127 - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/fstream#237
0x00407E2B - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/streambuf#465
0x004020AD - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/streambuf#151
0x00401434 - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware/ostream#683
0x00401276 - File3.cpp#13
The memory block (0x008922F0) [size: 512 bytes] was allocated with calloc
0x32A9D14F
0x004057B7 - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\dinkumware\xlocale#1289
0x00404DDA - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\dinkumware\xlocale#1261
0x004041F1 - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\dinkumware\xlocale#1268
0x00403395 - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\dinkumware\xlocale#323
0x004022AB - c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\../include/dinkumware
```

Thanks for your help.

**Updated question:**

Unfortunately this is an older and reported bug:
http://www.borlandtalk.com/is-there-a-bug-in-codeguard--vt112810.html

Topic can be closed...

Comment: You're missing a header (`<cstring>`), but apart from that your code looks _really twisted_ for what it does. Why all this complication?

Comment: Yes, it looks complicated. But it is only a testing example, I try to write the same data both into console and file.

Comment: Can you make `of` not static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building your project by statically linking against the runtime. You can do that by unchecking the option below:

[image: C++ Builder 2007]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked off "Dynamic RTL" and check on "Full Debug..." and "Disable incremental..." but the same results.